# Is there an algorithm to determine a point of divergence in two streams of data?

Tags: algorithm, hash, synchronization, replication

I have two data sources that should eventually contain the same data (i.e. a mobile app copy and a cloud backend copy). There are approximately 90k rows in the data source, and the mobile app has lost track of what it has replicated.

Is there an algorithm that can compactly and efficiently find and represent the point of divergence in the two streams? I know that each row is immutable.

The existing replication protocol in its current state will compare all ~90k local with all ~90k remote to determine what it needs to push and pull. However, I know (from inspection) that the mobile is only missing about 2k items from the remote.

I'd like to be able to generate a hash or checksum or something both locally and on the server that I can compare to determine the point at which the sources diverge. Does such an algorithm exist?

Answer (score 0):

The [rsync algorithm](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Enr/rsync.html) solves this problem pretty efficiently.

If you're willing to add metadata about commits like [git](https://git-scm.com/) does, then you can make it more efficient still.  Just like you thought it should, it uses commit hashes to figure out what the point of divergence is and to allow data to be replicated.  It can even figure out what happened if data arrived out of order.  Though with the possibility of problems from the potential for conflicts.

Then, of course, [Redis](https://redis.io/) already makes it really easy to set up and resume replication.  So that's an in memory solution to your problem with little code needed.

There exist other solutions with other tradeoffs.  But hopefully this is enough to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! We already have a system that replicates, but sometimes it gets out of sync and starts basically verifying from scratch (it uses a checkpoint on local and remote to know where to sync from and sometimes that resets to -1). I'll update the question with some more details.